# mostrar datos json

Tags: javascript, android-studio

por que me marca error en el response :  Log.d("Error.Response",response);

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    private void getacondicionado (){
        final String url = "http://192.198.20.123/SMART-TecMM/airesacondicionados/readAll";
        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                new Response.Listener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // display response
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response",response);
                    }
                }
        );

```
            Log.e( "onResponse: ","oaaa");
            getRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            GetRequestQueue.add(getRequest);
            queue.add(getRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `Log` te permite crear mensajes de registro que aparecen en el monitor de logcat. Por lo general, debes usar los siguientes métodos de registro, que se ordenan de mayor a menor prioridad:

`Log.e(String, String)` (error)

`Log.w(String, String)` (advertencia)

`Log.i(String, String)` (información)

`Log.d(String, String)` (depuración)

`Log.v(String, String)` (detalle)

Puede que tu variable **Response** no sea de tipo string.

Espero que te sea util

mas informacion en la [documentacion oficial](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es)